# How can i add webform at specific place in drupal?

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I have a webform in drupal page. I want to insert that webform at specific position in drupal with jquery. How can i place it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do. I like doing it with [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) method like below:

```
$(selector).appendTo(selector);
```

first selector is your form div and second selector is that div where you want to insert.

```
$('#my_form').appendTo('#my_position');
```

Comment: Both form and div is hard-coded so when i use this method it's remove from previous place and append in selector ?

Comment: yes, it removes from previous place and insert where you have appended.

Comment: Thanks C-link let me try :)